# Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, chrome-extension

I want to install the NetSpeed extension to monitor internet speed. but there is an error that say `Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.`

here is an screenshot:

[image]

I've searched for the solution, but it says to install chrome shell extension.
should it be ok to install it or it is deperected on ubuntu 21.10?

**update:**

1.

```
(base) ☁  ~  sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell

[sudo] password for mahdi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
chrome-gnome-shell is already the newest version (10.1-5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 intltool libgtkglext1
  libkeybinder-3.0-0 libminizip1 php8.0-sqlite3 python3-distutils-extra
  python3-levenshtein python3-pyinotify python3-websocket
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

2. I use Brave Browser which is chromium-based.
3. I have installed gnome browser extension extension

[image]

4. [image]

**update2:**

`snap list:`

[image]

`flatpak list`:

[image]

`dpkg -l *firefox*`:

[image]

Comment: Please see the two answers shown below. If one of them solves your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @heynnema, I've updated the question and provided more information. could you with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running the SNAP version of Firefox. Do `snap list` to confirm it.

Do this to remove the SNAP version of Firefox, and install the APT version of Firefox.

`sudo snap remove firefox`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install firefox`

Comment: Thanks, @heynnema, I used the snap version of firefox. and I run `sudo snap remove firefox` to remove firefox. I no longer use firefox. instead, I use brave which is chromium-based.
i checked and the issue is not solved.
do I need to install firefox again?

Comment: @MahdiJafari Edit your question and show me `snap list` and `flatpak list` and `dpkg -l *firefox*`. If the last command shows that `Firefox` is installed (otherwise insrtall it), please start it and go to the Netspeed web page and see if it works... I want to eliminate a problem with `Brave`.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema, I installed firefox and it worked!

Comment: @MahdiJafari Brave fails because it's also a SNAP. Do my answer to replace the SNAP version.

Comment: Yes, replacing snap version of firefox with apt version fixed the problem.

Comment: @MahdiJafari I was also suggesting that you do the same with brave and see if that fixes it too.

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be a bit confusing from [the official documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation), however, you can quickly resolve this by installing the `chrome-gnome-shell` package:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

This is the connector that works with the browser extension, and will work for Chrome, Chromium, Edge, and (possibly) other Chrome-based browsers. Once installed, refresh the Gnome Extensions page you're on and you should see a little toggle in the upper right corner:

[image: Toggle]

Comment: Thanks, @matigo, I run the command above, and those packages were installed on my machine. but the issue is not solved yet.